# How to get colliding effect or bouncy when ball hits the track

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, physics

```
                        ** STILL NOT WORKING **
```

I am using below formula to move the ball circular, where `accelX` and `accelY` are the values from accelerometer, it is working fine.

But the problem in this code is `mRadius` (I fixed its value to 50), i need to change `mRadius` according to accelerometer values and also i need bouncing effect when it touches the track. Currently i am developing code by assuming only one ball is on the board.

```
float degrees = -atan2(accelX, accelY);
int x = cCentrePoint.x + mRadius * cos(degrees);
int y = cCentrePoint.y + mRadius * sin(degrees);
```

Here is the snap of the game i want to develop:

[Balls Game http://iphront.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/bdece528ea334033.jpg.jpg](http://iphront.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/bdece528ea334033.jpg.jpg)

Updated: I am sending the updated code...

```
 mRadius = 5;
 mRange = NSMakeRange(0,60);

-(void) updateBall: (UIAccelerationValue) accelX 
                                  withY:(UIAccelerationValue)accelY
{

    float degrees = -atan2(accelX, accelY);
    int x = cCentrePoint.x + mRadius * cos(degrees);
    int y = cCentrePoint.y + mRadius * sin(degrees);

    //self.targetRect is rect of ball Object
    self.targetRect = CGRectMake(newX, newY, 8, 9);
    self.currentRect = self.targetRect;

    static NSDate *lastDrawTime;

    if(lastDrawTime!=nil)
    {
       NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastDraw =
                    -([lastDrawTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

       ballXVelocity = ballXVelocity + (accelX * secondsSinceLastDraw) 
               * [self isTouchedTrack:mRadius andRange:mRange];
       ballYVelocity = ballYVelocity + -(accelY * secondsSinceLastDraw) 
               * [self isTouchedTrack:mRadius andRange:mRange];

      distXTravelled = distXTravelled + secondsSinceLastDraw
                          * ballXVelocity * 50;
      distYTravelled = distYTravelled + secondsSinceLastDraw 
                          * ballYVelocity * 50;

      //Updating the ball rect  
      CGRect temp = self.targetRect;
      temp.origin.x += distXTravelled;
      temp.origin.y += distYTravelled;

      //calculating new radius after updating ball position
      int radius = (temp.origin.x - cCentrePoint.x) / 
                               cos(degreesToRadians(degrees));

     if( !NSLocationInRange(abs(radius),mRange))
     {
         //Colided with the tracks...Need a better logic here
      ballXVelocity = -ballXVelocity;
     }
     else
     {
           // Need a better logic here
       self.targetRect = temp; 
     }

  }

  [lastDrawTime release];
  lastDrawTime = [ [NSDate alloc] init];
}
```

In the above code i have initialized mRadius and mRange(indicate track) to some constant for testing, i am not getting the moving of the ball as i expected( bouncing effect when Collided with track ) with respect to accelerometer. Help me to recognize where i went wrong or send some code snippets or links which does the similar job.

I am searching for better logic than my code, if you found share with me.

Comment: Too vague - try asking a specific question ?

Comment: "touches other circles" mean "other balls" or "circles of the other tracks"?

Comment: I need the both effects when a ball touches other ball and also the track.

Comment: I am not familiar with the iPhone programming environment, but two things jump to my eyes:
1. Your curly braces do not seem balanced
2. You seem to be doing double-integration on the velocity. 1st for distXTravelled, then for temp.origin.x. I think in the first one you should omit the "distXTravelled +" part.

Comment: Aside: it's silly to convert from radians to degrees and then right back to radians.

Comment: Chandan, why are you summing "temp.origin.x += distXTravelled;"? You are performing an integration on the position. Instead, try "temp.origin.x = distXTravelled;".  EDIT: obviously, I am wrong here. Please ignore.

Comment: Can you please explain how you calculate the "radius", what is the purpose of "temp" (is it a static variable? if not, note that it is not initialized) and what is the purpose of the "degrees" variable? Why do you derive the radius from the tilting angle?

Comment: I am Identifying the tracks with radius,(for example outer-track radius is 140 from center, next track is at 100 from center...). So i am calculating radius of the ball after its position being updated so it can be used to check whether ball hits the tracks.(eg. If ball radius is 150, I can judge that it hits outer track).

Comment: "temp" is just a local variable, it is used to update the position of the ball. Instead of using "self.targetRect = CGRectMake(x,y,width,hight)" i have used temp variable.

Comment: "degrees" variable gives the tilted angle of iphone so i can update this angle with the ball.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you don't need (actually don't *want* the degrees variable. You have the direct reading of the ball's x and y acceleration components from the iPhone's accelerometers.

Comment: Upon collision with the track you reverse the x velocity, where what you should do is reverse the component of the velocity vector that is perpendicular to the wall, i.e., the component in the board's radial direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying alot I thought it is not easy to produce real time effect without using any physics engine. So its better to use BOX2d or Chipmunks or any other physics engines.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code correctly, then the ball's position is directly controlled by the iPhone's orientation (tilt). So, tilting the iPhone to the right will place the ball at the right side of the track (3 o'clock). I believe you may want the balls **acceleration** (or, at least, its velocity) to be controlled. Then, you integrate the acceleration to velocity and the velocity to place, taking into account the constraints (the track walls).

The way it is set now, I don't see how you'd control more than one ball (as per the image you posted).

Then, for the bouncing effect: if you mean bouncing by the track's wall, then this will be a small modulation of the mRadius. If you mean bounce by other ball, then you'd modulate the angular position (by means of angular velocity) of the two balls to reflect the reaction.

EDIT: for integration of acceleration to velocity and then to position, **for the purpose of this game**, you can do with 1st order rectangular integration. Also, it will be more realistic to make the acceleration proportional to the tilt angle. Given the accel values from the iPhone itself, you can assign a 1:1 relation between the balls accel and the device reading. So, you'd like something like:

```
BallAccX = AccelX * Am_I_NOT_touching_a_wall_in_X_direction() * Ka
BallVelX = BallVelX + BallAccX * dT * Kv
BallPosX = BallPosX + BallVelX * dT * Kp
```

Note: the above formulae for velocity and position are **1st order approximation** but should be sufficient for the purpose of this game.

Ka, Kv, Kp are some proportion coefficients. Choose them to make the relation between the sensed acceleration and the ball movement as you like. dT is the time difference between updates of the state of the ball. The function Am_I_NOT_touching_a_wall_in_X_direction() returns a 1 if the ball is free to move horizontally (in the direction of the tilt) and 0 otherwise.

Calculations for Y movement is symmetrical.

Comment: can you send some sample code which integrate the acceleration to velocity.

Comment: Well, it really depends on what "not smooth" means. It can be caused from many reasons. Until you dig it down, there is no sense in sticking to a specific "smoothing algorithm".